# Execute JavaScript Connector Stop Working

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-logic-apps

Execute JavaScript Connector Stop Working

I have just added just 2 lines of code to get data from first step and return that data.

Till yesterday i was working properly, but from today (5th September) its stop working.

find below code.

and Getting Unknown error

```
var data = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body;

return data;
```

Comment: Could you share what error it shows and did you define the trigger outputs? If no outputs it will show undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been mitigated. Could you please try again and let me know if still any issue.